# Replace $placeholder text in various configuration files with $placeholder parameter

Tags: shell-script, sed, parameter

I am at my wits end trying to get sed to do this for me and I feel like an idiot. So I hope someone has a much smarter way to accomplish what seems to be incredibly simple.

file.conf:

```
USER: !USER!
```

script.sh:

```
param=$1
# something to replace !USER! with $param
```

file.conf after running `script.sh squirrel`:

```
USER: squirrel
```

Comment: What did you try, and how exactly did it fail?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want, or what's going wrong, but you want something like: `sed -i'' "s/^USER: \!USER\!/USER: $param/" file.conf` perhaps?

Comment: I think my issue may have been that I wasn't escaping `!` - or maybe using single quotes? My result would be to get "$param" as the replacement value in the text, rather than the value that was behind the variable `$param`.

Comment: Is your configuration file a YAML document?

Comment: One of them. There are multiple documents and document types being modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sed` command to achieve that.
Let's say on your `file.conf` you have:

```
USER: !USER!
USER: !USER2!
USER: !USER
USER: !USER!
```

In your `script.sh` file you should have:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

param=$1

sed -i'.bak' "s/\!USER\!/$param/" /path/to/file.conf
```

With `-i` argument the sed command will edit the file in place. The `.bak` is  the backup of your file, so if your file is `file.conf`, its backup will be `file.conf.bak`.

The `"s/\!USER\!/$param/"` is used for substituting a value for another one. For example, `\!USER\!/$param` means that sed will replace the strings `!USER!` for `$param` (where $param contains the string you specify in command line).

Finally, if you run the `script.sh` with `./script.sh squirrel` you will see that the `file.conf` has changed. The output will be this:

```
USER: squirrel
USER: !USER2!
USER: !USER
USER: squirrel
```

As you can see only the first and last lines `!USER!` have changed.

**Warnings:**

1. When you use `sed -i'.bak'` make sure there is no space between `-i` and `.bak`.
2. If the `$params` variable contains special characters like `\`, `/`, `&` the `sed` command will fail, so you will have to escape those characters by prefixing `\`. For example, if you want to pass the value `'fuzz&'` you should use `'fuzz\&'`.
3. When you pass the string to `script.sh` make sure you are using single quotes `'` and not double quotes `"`. If you want to use `"` and your string contains the character `` ` `` (backtick) or `\` you will have to escape this one with the prefix `\`:

```bash
./script.sh "fuzz\`" # "fuzz\`" will be "fuzz`"
#or
./script.sh "fuzz\\\\" # "fuzz\\\\" will be "fuzz\"
```

Thanks to frabjous and Philippos for their observations.

Comment: I think that should be `sed -e "s/!USER!/$param/" file...` as double-quotes will pass the `\!` as-is, and it's undefined in standard BRE. Or use `sed -e 's/!USER!/'"$param/" file...` if you're worried about hitting history expansion, but in a script it should not be active anyway.

Comment: @ilkkachua the second example  is useful, it works great. But about the first one, it should not be with single quotes? I tested it with double quotes and didn't work because of the history expansion.

Comment: yes, that's what I was saying, to use the one with single quotes if history expansion is a concern. If you have the command in a script, history expansion should be disabled and I think history expansion should be disabled in noninteractive shells by default. (well, if they asked me, it should be disabled in _interactive_ shells by default too, but, oh well.)

Comment: @ilkkachu oh, I got it now :D ! And just like that, I tested again in a script (as non interactive shell) and the history expansion it's ignored. And I also tried to use an interactive shell with `#! /bin/bash -i` and didn't because of the history expansion.

Comment: Thanks, I've learned something new now :)